# Проблема с static readonly PropertyData в обобщенном классе используя Catel

Tags: wpf, catel

Использую WPF Catel.
Столкнулся с проблемой:

```
//обошенный класс унаследованный от ModelBase


public sealed class TestType<T> : ModelBase
 {

      #region Constructor

      public TestType() 
      {
      }

      #endregion


      #region Properties

      public ushort Val
      {
           get { return GetValue<ushort>(ValProperty); }
           set { SetValue(ValProperty, value); }
      }
      public static readonly PropertyData ValProperty = RegisterProperty("Val", typeof(ushort));

      #endregion
 }
```

//ВьюМодель гдя я использую Модель

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
     {
          #region Properties

          [Model]
          public TestType<bool> Xxx
          {
               get { return GetValue<TestType<bool>>(XxxProperty); }
               set { SetValue(XxxProperty, value); }
          }
          public static readonly PropertyData XxxProperty = RegisterProperty("Xxx", typeof(TestType<bool>));

          #endregion


          #region Commands

          private Command _editCommand;
          public Command EditCommand
          {
               get
               {
                    return _editCommand ?? (_editCommand = new Command(
                        () =>
                        {
                             Xxx = new TestType<bool>();
                        },
                        () => true));
               }
          }


  #endregion

}
```

при присваивании в теле команды возникает исключение Xml сереализации, когда Xxx помечен атрибутом [Model].

И решарпер ругается:  статичное поле в обобщенном классе

```
public static readonly PropertyData XxxProperty
```

Если класс TestType сделать обычным то ошибки не будет.
Сделать PropertyData не статичным не получается ругается катель.
Подскажите пожалуйста как быть.

Comment: Простите, а что такое `Catel`? Это какая-то внутренняя проблема класса `ModelBase`, судя по всему. Где у вас в коде Xml-сериализация, непонятно.

А сообщение от решарпера к проблеме отношения не имеет (и скорее всего оно просто ошибочно).

Comment: Catel это фреймворк для работы с WPF. искал тэг catel на форуме но не нашел, поместил вопрос в раздел WPF. сереализация там происходит внутреними механизмами кателя при присваивании (чтобы работал откат к предыдущему состоянию). Понимаю что вопрос специфичен. но куда его задать не знаю

Comment: @Aldmi: Понятно. Проблема судя по всему где-то в конфигурации Catel, т. к. ошибка говорит о сериализации.

Answer (score 3):

Почему ругается РеШарпер: он предупреждает вас, что для каждого `T` в `TestType<>` будет отдельное значение поля `ValProperty`. Часто это не то, чего хочет программист, потому что в недженериковых классах значение у статического поля только одно.

Почему ругается Катель: пожалуйста, приведите полное сообщение об ошибке. Из кода непонятно, зачем вам сдался атрибут Model на свойстве в `MainWindowViewModel` — что куда вы хотите мапить?

Comment: Почему решарпер ругается я понимаю, но почему у свойств кателя нету дженерик версии на такие случаи?

XmlException не обработанно.
Знак "`", шестнадцатеричное значение 0x60, не может использоваться в именах.

Буду мапить из TestType свойства, просто не привел всего кода.

Ограничился малым куском чтобы было понятно что именно этот код приводит к ошибке

Comment: все крутится вокруг аттрибута Model на дженерик классе у которого есть поле для маппинга не дженерик, но оно должно быть кателевским свойством